# How do write sql query to fix data issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help in fixing data issue with sql query. I don't know even can it be achieved with SQL query or not, can anybody help me please.

Mysql database has two tables named:

1. Employee

employee table has four below columns:

```
employeeid, accountid, name, job
1            1         sagar  1
2            1         kumar  1
3            2         kumar  1
```

Primary key for table is composite key (employeeid, accountid);

2. Effective_dated Employee

effective_dated_employee table has five below columns:

```
employeeid, effective_start, effective_end, termiation, joing
1          2000-1-1         2021-1-1      T            2000-01-01
1          2012-1-1         2012-02-1     T            2012-01-1
2          2000-1-1         2021-1-1      T            2000-01-01
2          2012-1-1         2012-02-1     T            2012-01-1
3          2000-1-1         2021-1-1      T            2000-01-01
```

Primary key for table is composite (employeeid, effective_start, effective_end) where employeeid is foreign key reference to employee -> employeeid

Now I have added a new acoountId column in effective_dated_employee which will also be part of composite key and is a foreign key reference to employee->accountid

Problem: I want to update effective_dated_employee account column from employee table account column like

```
employeeid, effective_start, effective_end, termiation, joing       accountid
1          2000-1-1         2021-1-1        T            2000-01-01   1
1          2012-1-1         2012-02-1       T            2012-01-1    1
2          2000-1-1         2021-1-1        T            2000-01-01   1
2          2012-1-1         2012-02-1       T            2012-01-1    1
3          2012-1-1         2012-02-1       T            2012-01-1    2
```

How can I achieve this with sql query. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You appear to be describe `JOIN`.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to join two tables like this:

```
update effective_dated_employee ede
join Employee e on (e.employeeid = ede.employeeid)
set ede.accountid = e.accountid
```

I have created a demo for this :

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=899f31e8ef5fd4ef693c9304710d4372)

Comment: Wow. I never knew it would be that easy. Thank you very much.